# Problem to use ajax POST with codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, json, codeigniter

I'm working on a project that is like a ticket system, sometimes it requires some very long answers, in the answer area I use CKEDITOR while the agent it's typing automatically saves the changes to the database using Json GET, but some long answers are not working, the following error shows up:

```
    Request-URI Too Long
The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity limit for this server.
Additionally, a 414 Request-URI Too Long error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I found out that was caused for the use of GET and I was adviced to change it to POST after that I don't have that error, now I'm getting 403 forbidden

this is the json code

```
CKEDITOR.replace('consulta-body', {
  height: '300',
  on: {
      change: function( evt ) {
            for ( instance in CKEDITOR.instances ){
              CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
            }
          var BodyText = $('#consulta-body').val();
          console.log( BodyText ); 

          var FormData = {};
          FormData['update'] = '1';
          FormData['id'] = <? echo $this->uri->segment(3);?>;
          FormData['name'] = 'previo';
             FormData['val'] = BodyText;
          $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: FormData,
            url: '<?echo base_url('consultas/ver/1212');?>',
            beforeSend: function(){},
            success: function(Response){}
          });
        }
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
Tried this, no errors nothing on console but its not saving to database

```
CKEDITOR.replace('consulta-body', {
  height: '300',
  on: {
      change: function( evt ) {
            for ( instance in CKEDITOR.instances ){
              CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
            }
          var BodyText = $('#consulta-body').val();
          console.log( BodyText ); 

        var FormData = {};
          FormData['<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>']
                       = '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>';
          FormData['update'] = '1';
          FormData['id'] = <? echo $this->uri->segment(3);?>;
          FormData['name'] = 'previo';
             FormData['val'] = BodyText;
          $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: FormData,
            url: '<?echo base_url('consultas/ver/1212');?>',
            beforeSend: function(){},
            success: function(Response){}
          });
        }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are getting that because this `<?echo base_url('consultas/ver/1212');?>` is generating an error.

You can either write it like this:

`<?php echo base_url('consultas/ver/1212'); ?>`

OR like this:

`<?= base_url('consultas/ver/1212'); ?>`

See:
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/alternative_php.html

*note this error appears a few times in your code so revise all erroneous blocks*

Comment: tried both options, the data it's not saving to database yet :(

Comment: Well it sounds like I resolved your question then. I can't see what you haven't posted. So I'm not sure why you have issues somewhere else down the line.